# How to change locale for cin

Tags: c++, console, locale, cin, setlocale

I have two languages in my Ubuntu. And I want to start my simple program but need to enter the data in different languages. I am tired to switch global toggle from one lang to another. And now I am trying to automate this process by following code:

```
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
void change_locale(bool lang)
{
    std::locale delocale("de_DE.utf8");
    std::locale enlocale("en_AG");

    if (lang == true){
        std::cout << "set DE locale" << '\n';
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE.utf8");
        std::locale::global(delocale);
        std::cin.imbue(delocale);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "set Eng locale" << '\n';
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_AG");
        std::locale::global(enlocale);
        std::cin.imbue(enlocale);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Please pay attention it is applied for cin only. How to make it workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, found the solution with `setxkbmap` utility.
I've created two scripts where the command is called

- de.sh file `setxkbmap de`
- en.sh file `setxkbmap en`

and then call it from the source code

```
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
void change_locale(bool lang)
{
    std::locale delocale("de_DE.utf8");
    std::locale enlocale("en_AG");

    if (lang == true){
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE.utf8");
        std::locale::global(delocale);
        std::cin.imbue(delocale);
        system("de.sh");
    }
    else {
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_AG");
        std::locale::global(enlocale);
        std::cin.imbue(enlocale);
        system("en.sh");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're after is changing the keyboard layout.  Unfortunately the C++ locale won't affect this.  You need to interact with the operating system, specifically the [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) subsystem.  There are some instructions here for Ubuntu which you've said you are using: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813094/how-to-change-uim-ime-input-method-using-command-line-or-programmatically/967787

The gist is that you need to open a Unix Domain Socket `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/uim/socket/uim-helper` and write a specific message like this:

```
im_change_whole_desktop
anthy
<one blank line with trailing newline>
```